# Is there any substance whose vapor-liquid coexistence area appears leaned?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, gas, phase-diagram

The usual substance whose vapor-liquid coexistence area appears like that shown in following Fig.1

[image: Fig.1]

My question is: is there any substance whose vapor-liquid coexistence area looks leaned,
i.e., $V_{vapor}<V_c$ for some isothermal whose temperature is below the critical one, as sketched in following Fig.2.

[image: Fig.2]

Comment: Are you looking for a one-component system or it is also allowed to indicate mixtures?

Comment: It is hard to disprove the existence of such a phase diagram for a one-component system.    Thus, I want to know if this kind of phase diagram would appear for any system, whenever one-component or binary or mixture.

Answer (score 2):

Not a definite answer, but hopefully some useful relations and hints to find one.

This question is equivalent to asking if it is allowed and under which conditions the slope of the vapor side of the liquid-vapor coexistence region in the $p-V$ plane may be negative.

I think I have never seen experimental data showing this kind of behavior. However, something can be said on the theoretical side as a help to show that it is at least possible, and to find the conditions for such behavior.

If we denote by $\sigma$ data on the coexistence line in the $T-p$ plane, manipulating the differential of $V(p, T)$, we get an expression for the derivative of the volume with respect to pressure at the coexistence (see  J S Rowlinson F L Swinton *Liquids and Liquid Mixtures*, Butterworth-Heinemann, 1982):
$$
\frac{1}{V}\left.\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{p}}\right|_\sigma =
\frac{1}{V}\left.\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{p}}\right|_T + 
 \frac{1}{V}\left.\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{T}}\right|_p
\left.\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{p}}\right|_\sigma=-\chi_T+\alpha_p\left.\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{p}}\right|_\sigma \tag{1}
$$
where the partial derivatives corresponding to isothermal compressibility ($\chi_T $) and thermal expansion coefficient ($\alpha_p $)have been identified.

Thermodynamic stability requires $\chi_T>0$. There is no thermodynamic restriction, in general, on the sign of $\alpha_p$ and $\left.\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{p}}\right|_\sigma$. However, while we know examples of liquids with a negative thermal expansion (the most well-known is water between $0$ and $4$ $^{\circ}$C ), usually this quantity is positive in the gas phase. Moreover, in the the case of the liquid-vapor coexistence line,  also $\left.\frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{p}}\right|_\sigma $ is expected to be positive (Clausius-Clapeyron equation).

Therefore, the sign of the slope of the pressure versus volume depends on the balance between the first and the second term on the right-hand side of Eq. $(1)$. The best candidates for such a behavior could probably be systems with the maximum change of volume at the transition and the smallest latent heat.